# Ordering rows in a dataframe based on order of rows in another, with different dimensions

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, dplyr, match

So I have two dataframes. First one:

```
DF1
Country Score

India   12
India   14
India   10
China   9
China   16
USA     14
USA     12
USA     17
USA     10
Nepal   7
...
```

And I want to reorder the entire thing based upon the order of countries in a second dataframe:

```
DF2
Country

China
USA
India
Nepal
Zimbabwe
Solomon Islands
...
```

Attempted a few variations using `match`, `arrange` etc. in dplyr without much luck. i.e:

```
DF1[order(match(DF1$country, DF2$country)), ]
```

But it doesn't work. Other methods get caught out by the differences in dataframe length etc., and I'd like a solution that doesn't involve me spaghetti-coding together some iterative loop. Any suggestions?

Outcome ought to be:

```
DF1
Country Score

China   9
China   16
USA     14
USA     12
USA     17
USA     10
India   12
India   14
India   10
Nepal   7
...
```

P.S. Even better if I can also sort the Score in descending order, but I'd like to try that myself first.

Thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure this has been answered before somewhere, but while I look for a duplicate you can use an ordered factor - `DF1[order(ordered(DF1$Country, levels=DF2$Country)),]`

Comment: Also, your code `DF1[order(match(DF1$Country, DF2$Country)), ]` works perfectly if you make sure that you specify `Country` not `country` for each column.

Comment: Neither my original attempt nor your suggestion works; I did see this asked before (where I got the code from) but as mentioned found it didn't work, despite being careful with syntax and spelling. Hmmm...
This is a mock version of my data so perhaps there's something else I need to consider.

Comment: You might have to break each piece of code out and see why it doesn't work on your actual data. I.e., look what you get for the `match` part, then the `order` part, and see where it might be giving an unexpected result. It's hard to tell what it might be, but it definitely works on this simplified data.

Comment: So: `countryorder<-c(DF2$Country)`
`match(DF1$country, countryorder)`

Returns everything as NA.

Attempting again with `match(DF1$country, c("China"))` returns everything NA except those which do indeed match as China. Hmmm, for whatever reason it seems like it's just not iterating through the ordered list from DF2. 
One solution is to manually type out the full vector list of countries... But yup, the whole matching/ordering thing works otherwise - thanks!

Comment: Maybe spaces around your `DF2$Country` variables? Try again with `countryorder<- trimws(DF2$Country)` - if that doesn't work I'm out of ideas though.

Comment: Yup; just noticed I needed to remove spaces / indents from the .csv data. Works now; thanks!